# Invalid verification token Facebook API webhook

Tags: python, facebook, flask, bots, ngrok

I am trying to link my flask app.py messages bot try ngrok to facebook but I run into this problem
I get after I write ngrok address in browser:

```
Invalid verification token
```

I set verify token in facebook  same like in my app.py file

Here is the code:

```
    VERIFY_TOKEN = 'fashionstorebot123'
bot = Bot(ACCESS_TOKEN)

#We will receive messages that Facebook sends our bot at this endpoint 
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def receive_message():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        """Before allowing people to message your bot, Facebook has implemented a verify token
        that confirms all requests that your bot receives came from Facebook."""
        token_sent = request.args.get('hub.verify_token')
        return verify_fb_token(token_sent)

def verify_fb_token(token_sent):
#take token sent by facebook and verify it matches the verify token you sent
#if they match, allow the request, else return an error 
if token_sent == VERIFY_TOKEN:
    return request.args.get("hub.challenge")
return 'Invalid verification token'
```

Any help why this happen Verify_TOKEN is same in facebook.

Comment: So what does _“after I write ngrok address in browser”_ mean, _exactly_? Did you specify the necessary parameters for this to work properly, or …?

Comment: yes I specify hgrok http 500 facebook. Facebook don`t return verify token I think

Comment: How is that an answer to what I asked you!?! Again: What exactly did you put into your browser address bar?

Comment: _“Facebook don`t return verify token I think”_ - or maybe you did not understand how this works to begin with, I think? When you try to _test_ your script by making such a GET request inside of your own browser, then _you_ would have to supply that parameter, of course.

Comment: https:// addressnumber.ngrok.io/ I test it when i send a message to the page I am linked to but without respond

Comment: With curl command I pass hub.challenge.So I get the point but bot just don`t message back in messanger

Comment: It makes no sense to expect to see anything in that place. If you want to see any requests made from the outside (_by_ Facebook), then you need to go and visit the dashboard ngrok provides for that - https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started-inspect

Comment: Ok thank you that will help.